# How can I choose which firefox executable to use among multiple firefox binaries through Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm using python (v 3.65) selenium (v3.11.0) on Mac OS X (v 10.11.6) with firefox (v 59.0.3) and geckodriver (v 0.20.1).  I have my usual firefox in the Applications folder and a second firefox in another folder.  How can I tell python selenium to use the second firefox instead of going to the one in Applications?

I'd prefer an answer that generalises to other browsers besides firefox/geckodriver, if possible.

Comment: You can use `DesiredCapabilities` to firefox profile and set `binary` attribute to it. [Check this answer for implementation details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40931903/5741172)

Comment: The firefox_capabilities trick didn’t work.  Renaming the firefox in the Applications folder caused my test script to fail with “Unable to find a matching set of capabilities”.  Renaming the firefox in the other folder made no difference either way.  So python/selenium/geckodriver isn’t using firefox_capabilities to find the firefox executable.  Maybe this is more of a Mac OS X question than a selenium question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To choose and use one of the *Firefox* executable among multiple you can use the argument **binary_location** from **firefox.options**. As an example in the following code block I have used the *Firefox Nightly*  binary to open the *Firefox Nightly* browser :

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe'
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  print("Firefox Browser Invoked")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  Firefox Browser Invoked
  ```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  Works on OS X as well as Windows.